# Difference between trigger, handler and callback

Tags: terminology, concepts

It's current to see the terms `callback`, `trigger` and `handler` in some API documentations. It is just synonymous or each term correspond to a specific concept?

I used to think that this terms are just synonymous, but I must be wrong ...

Thanks !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are general terms in programming. Often can mean different things but generally speaking...

`callback` is a reference to a function or block of code that is executed by a third party.

`trigger` is a behavior in response to stimuli, and an event may `trigger` the change of state or as the result of that `trigger` execute the associated `callback`.

`handler` is a reference to an object or class that is associated with a behavior. A `handler` is different from a `callback` because it's an object that represents a state.

Using jQuery AJAX as an example.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "test.html",
   context: document.body
}).done(function() {
   $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

- The `function()` is a `callback`.
- The object passed to `$.ajax(...)` is a `handler`.
- The event `done()` is a `trigger`.

The `handler` has an event `done` that when `triggered` calls the `callback` to perform `$(this).addClass("done");`.

Comment: is a `handler` executed by a third party too ? By a `trigger` by example? is a `handler`  just a complex `callback` ?

Comment: `handler` is like a `callback` except that it can do multiple things, where as a `callback` is singular. A `handler` might handle success, timeout or errors as an example.

Comment: A handler can also be a function.

Comment: @tdammers In *your* opinion, what's the difference between a `handler` and a `callback` then ?

Comment: @nouney: it's a conceptual difference more than a technical one. 'Callback' refers to the technical mechanism of passing function A to function B, and then having B call A as part of its processing. 'Handler' highlights the intent that some sort of event is handled; this is often done with callbacks, but there are other mechanisms that one can use for this.

Comment: @tdammers For me the difference is in the signature of how it's references. Callbacks in most languages (C++,C#,Java,PHP) use a function signature. A handler is often an instantiated object. For strongly typed languages like (C++,C#,Java) these objects often implement a specific interface. I do agree that a handler is intent driven. Another way of thinking of a `callback` is to say `come back to this code later`. I think a handler is not that generic. It's more like `run this code IF rule X is true`, but it's true it doesn't have to be an object it can just be a function.

Answer (score 2):

Handler, an asynchronous callback subroutine.  Handler implements **interceptor design** pattern.  Which is used to handle incoming or outgoing messages and manipulate its values.

A callback is a piece of executable code that is passed as an argument to other code, which is expected to call back (execute) the argument at some convenient time. The invocation may be immediate as in a **synchronous callback**, or it might happen at later time as in an **asynchronous callback**.
Callbacks implements in different ways Closure , lambda expressions and so on...

**Triggers** are rules, it executes on **events**.